# How to remove HTML tags from ckeditor to textarea

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to create a simple blog that has a post article function that contains a ckeditor. When I insert text from ckeditor and store it in the database, I want to get the content from the database to show it on my index page.

The problem is that it can show the content but it displays the HTML tags

[image: Screenshot of blog post. It contains visible paragraph tags around the text.]

Comment: Please provide code and add the image to your question rather than a link so that people can see the complete question even if the link goes dead in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display string as Html in ASP.NET.MVC use this one:

```
@Html.Raw(@Model.PropertyName)
```

where `PropertyName` is the name of your property